# Construction of Hilbert Variety (in Harris' Algebraic Geometry)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, moduli-space, hilbert-polynomial

My question intends to take up a detail in the construction of the Hilbert variety in Harris' book
Algebraic Geometry; A First Course (p 274).

Let $S=K[X_0,X_1,..., X_n]$ be the ring of polynomials in $n+1$ indeterminants and
denote by $S_m$ the $K$-vector space of homogeneous polynomials
of degree $m$ in $S$. It is known that $\dim_K S_m = \binom{m+n}{n}$. Let
$\Lambda \subset S_m$ any $K$-subspace of dimension $d$. For any positive integer $k$
we have a natural multiplication map

$$ \Psi_{\Lambda, k}: \Lambda \otimes S_k \to S_{k+m}  $$

multiplying the two homogeneous polynomials in $\Lambda \subset S_m$ ans $S_k$. Clearly it's
well defined and $K$-linear.

I think that the rank of $\Psi_{\Lambda, k}$ should depend only on $d= \dim \ \Lambda$ and
$k$, but not $\Lambda$ itself; see my arguments below. But going through the conttruction of Hilbert variety in Harris' book would give strange results.
At first why I think it should depend only on $d$ (and $k$), but not on the choice of $\Lambda$ itself? If $ \overline{\Lambda}$ is another $d$-dimensional
subspace of $S_m$ then $\Lambda$ and $\overline{\Lambda}$ are isomorphic /projectively
equivalent since $PSL_n(K)$ induces an action on every homogeneous part $S_m$ and
it acts transitively on every
$d$-Grassmannian $G_d(S_m)=\{ \Lambda \ \ \Lambda \subset S_m, \dim_K \ \Lambda=d \}$.

Therefore it seems that the rank $\operatorname{rank} (\Psi_{\Lambda, k})$ depends only
on $d$ and $k$, not $\Lambda$ since $\Psi_{\Lambda, k}$ and $\Psi_{\overline{\Lambda}, k}$
differ by a precomposition with an isomorphism induced by $PSL_n(K)$ that maps
$\Lambda$ to $\overline{\Lambda}$.

Let now consider the sketch of the construction Hilbert variety in Harris book (p. 274):

> The naively constructed set-theoretic map

$$H: \{ \text{ subvarieties } X \subset \mathbb{P}^n 
\text{ with Hilbert polynomial } p =p_X \} \to G= G(q(m), N(m))$$

> (where $N(m)=\binom{m+n}{n}$ and $q(m)= N(m)-p(m)$) in called Hilbert map.

> In fact, the open Hilbert variety is a quasi-projective subset of the Grassmannian
> $G= G(q(m), N(m))$. To see this, observe that for any vector subspace A c Sm and any
> positive integer k, we have a multiplication map

$$ \Psi_{\Lambda, k}: \Lambda \otimes S_k \to S_{k+m}  $$

if we have a subspace $\Lambda \subset S_m$ of codimension $p(m)$ (so dimension $q(m)$)
it will be the $m$th graded
piece of the ideal $I(X)$ of a variety $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ with Hilbert polynomial $p$ if and
only if for every $k$ the rank of $\Psi_{\Lambda, k}$ is what it should be, that is, $q(m + k)$.

But recalling my considerations above the rank of $\Psi_{\Lambda, k}$ seemingly depends only on $q(m)$
and $k$ but not subspace $\Lambda$ itself. So the rank of $\Psi_{\Lambda, k}$
is the same for all $q(m)$ dimensional subspaces $\Lambda \subset S_m$?

But in this case the definition of Hilbert scheme via ranishing rank condition make no sense
since then *every* subspace of $S_m$ of dimension $q(m)$ would satisfy this rank condition.
But that's not really what one wants, this would imply that the set of points of Hilbert variety is the complete Grassmannian $G= G(q(m), N(m))$ or it is empty! Can
somebody resolve my confusion around the rank of $ \Psi_{\Lambda, k}$ and it's dependence on
concrete space $\Lambda$.

Comment: In $K\left[X,Y\right]$, the two subspaces $\left<X^2,Y^2\right> \cdot \left<X, Y\right>$ and $\left<X^2,XY\right> \cdot \left<X, Y\right>$ (where the angular brackets mean spans) have different dimensions ($4$ and $3$, respectively). This should contradict your guess, or am I misreading it?

Comment: Why should $PSL_n\left(K\right)$ act transitively on $G_d\left(S_m\right)$? This should be wrong for dimension reasons for high enough $d$ and $m$.

Comment: @darij: Yes you're right, I thought too sloppily about it, the transitivity of 
described action is indeed wrong in general. Thanks!